# What does @ sign means here

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

Can you please tell me what does @ means here?

> acceptFileTypes: '@'

```
$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.processQueue.push(
        {
            action: 'validate',
            // Always trigger this action,
            // even if the previous action was rejected: 
            always: true,
            // Options taken from the global options map:
            acceptFileTypes: '@',
            maxFileSize: '@',
            minFileSize: '@',
            maxNumberOfFiles: '@',
            disabled: '@disableValidation'
        }
    )
```

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki--options

Comment: @GuyT: That's incorrect. It means that `acceptFileTypes` will have the same value as the global `acceptFileTypes` option (if a certain condition is met).

Comment: @FelixKling I've deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki--options):

> **@-Options**
>
> Each property of a process queue item that starts with an "@"-sign  will be assigned its value following this set of rules:
>
> - Remove the "@"-sign.
> - If the resulting string is not empty, set the property value to the global option of the same name. e.g. `disabled: '@disableVideoPreview'` will be set to the global `disableVideoPreview` option.
>
>   - If the property string is empty, check if the process object has the `prefix` property set to true:
>
>     - If no, set its value to the global option with the same name as the property. e.g. `acceptFileTypes: '@'` will be set to the global `acceptFileTypes` option.
>     - If yes, set its value to the global option with name of the property plus its action value as prefix in camel case. e.g. `fileTypes: '@'` from the `loadVideo` process above will be set to the global `loadVideoFileTypes` option, as the prefix property is set to true.

So, basically it means that the option will have the same value as the global option with the same (or a similar) name.

---

It's always good to read the documentation *before* you use a new tool (or at least look at the documentation when you are unsure about something).

Comment: Thanks @Felix, I do but somehow I missed this part.